# Beautiful paper prints with Emacs

Tags: printing, emacs, source-code

Is it possible to get beautiful prints in GNU Emacs? By default using M-x print-buffer the output looks ugly, with big fonts and no margin.

For source code it would be nice to get a pretty font, syntax highlighting, a header and line numbering.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest using <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `ps-print-buffer-with-faces`, it looks much nicer.

Comment: This is what I usually do from emacs, but `enscript` provided tons of flexibility if you find this to be deficient in some way.

Answer (score 5):

Download [a2ps](http://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/); it does what you're looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might find [this page about printing on the Emacs Wiki helpful](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/PrintingFromEmacs).

The two most interesting options on there are:

- [Printing with the Web Browser](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrintWithWebBrowser) - Emacs produces some nicely formatted HTML from your code and you print that from your browser
- [Printing with Word](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrintUsingWord)

I have to admit I haven't tried either.

Answer (score 2):

[`enscript`](http://www.gnu.org/software/enscript/)

Similar in spirit to a2ps. My link is to the GNU version, but I think that Adobe provided the original.